# How to print unicode-character-codes-stored-as-strings as human-readable text

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have lots of unicode characters codes **stored as strings** in Python3, e.g.

`unicode = '3077'`

where U+3077 is ぷ. How do I print this as human-readable text? I.e. how do I convert the string `unicode` to `unicode_as_text` such that:

```
>>> print(unicode_as_text)
ぷ
```

Comment: That's not "unicode-stored-as-a-string". Unicode stored as a string would just be `'ぷ'`.

Comment: Thanks, changed to "unicode-character-codes-stored-as-strings".

Comment: The character you are seeing as the string is the human readable text. What are you expecting to see?
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3077/index.htm

Comment: The string I currently have is `'3077'`. I want to see `'ぷ'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is the unicode codepoint represented in hexdecimal, so the character can be rendered by printing the result of calling [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) on the decimal value of the code point.

```
>>> print(chr(int('3077', 16)))
ぷ
```